# Magneto 2.2.0 add header and footer to checkout page

Tags: magento2

How to add header and footer to checkout page. I used the override method. I created `checkou_index_index.xml` file in following path `layout\override\theme\Magento\blank` in my custom theme.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="minicart" remove="false" />
    <referenceContainer name="header.panel" remove="false" />
    <referenceBlock name="top.search" remove="false" />
    <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.link" remove="false" />
    <referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav" remove="false"/>
    <referenceContainer name="footer-container"  remove="false"/>
</body>
</page>
```

But I received following error.

```
Overriding view file 'C:\/xampp\/htdocs\/my_website\/app\/design\/frontend\/Vendor\/basic\/Magento_Checkout\/layout\/override\/theme\/Magento\/blank\/checkout_index_index.xml' does not match to any of the files
```

What is the cause of this error and how to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

First you have to create custom theme and once its done then create **checkout_index_index.xml** file in **app/design/frontend/Magenticians/Mytheme/Magento_Checkout/layout** and paste this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="minicart" remove="false" />
    <referenceContainer name="header.panel" remove="false" />
    <referenceBlock name="top.search" remove="false" />
    <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.link" remove="false" />
    <referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav" remove="false"/>
    <referenceContainer name="footer-container"  remove="false"/>
</body>
</page>
```

Then create customcss.css in app/design/frontend/Magenticians/Mytheme/web/css and paste this code:

```
.action-auth-toggle
{
display: block;
}
```

Now open a default.xml file of your custom theme and paste this code:

```
<head>
        <css src="css/customcss.css" />
</head>
```

After the implementation, don't forget to run necessary CLI commands.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your custom xml file in:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\my_website\app\design\frontend\Vendor\basic\Magento_Checkout\view\frontend\layout\checkout_index_index.xml
```

Because, if i'm not mistaken, the file to override is in:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\my_website\vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\layout\checkout_index_index.xml
```

Hope this helps you.